# Initialise or append dictionary list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, initialization

Can the following code snippet be simplified into one statement somehow?

```
if aKey not in aDict:
    aDict[aKey] = [someValue]
else: 
    aDict[aKey].append(someValue)
```

I could write a function accepting the `aDict`, `aKey` and `someValue`, but is there a way to do this using only native python stuff?

Comment: You should look at [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) this is exactly what the container was made for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is made just with this purpose in mind:

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: d = collections.defaultdict(list)

In [3]: d['key'].append(1)

In [4]: d
Out[4]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key': [1]})

In [5]: d['key'].append(2)

In [6]: d
Out[6]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key': [1, 2]})
```

Here, when you access a key that does not exist, it is automatically initialised with an empty list.